# Ladies/Gentlemen vs. Women/Men to describe a group of people

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was talking to a taxi driver over the phone and was describing a passenger 
group, who is my mom and her friend. I said:

> Please find two middle-aged **ladies** in front of the building.

I thought this might be a broken English or a weird expression.
Should I just use "women"?

Comment: Why do you think “ladies” is inappropriate?

Comment: Hmm, I have no specific reason. English is my second language, so I was just not sure about the usage of the word.

Comment: 'Ladies' is gentlemanly, 'middle-aged'  less so.

Comment: The choice between **ladies** and **women** is yours. It's a matter of preference and generally of context. If the females were my relatives, I'd have said **two ladies**. If I'd called the taxi to take home two females clad in working overalls, I'd probably have said **two women**. Propriety is a guide. But there's no rule.

Comment: What do you mean by “broken English"?

Comment: MaxHeap, I think Colleen is trying to say that we might be able to compose a better answer if you could pinpoint why you suspect "ladies" might be less-than-appropriate. For example, do you think the term might sound dated, rude, stilted, or unnatural? It's an interesting question, but a little more information could make it even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Woman" is the neutral term in English for an adult female person.

"Lady" suggests a person of high social standing. It can be used refer to a woman in a formal or polite way, but it also suggests that the woman is particularly respectable.

In the example you give, you can choose between "lady" or "woman", it is up to you.

Some women don't like to be called "ladies" as it suggests that they should behave more politely and nicely. In the same way, some men don't like to be called "sir". Recently, for example, Chelsea ladies football club renamed itself as "Chelsea women" because they thought that "ladies" gave the wrong impression that they were "nice", when really they were "tough".